# Android - Passing more variebles via intent makes app crash

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-intent, crash

So, here is the code from the main activity(the main screen,) if you click on play a random activity( a quiz question) will show up. The problem is that, i am trying to pass an integer, default score to question #1, where the score will be 5(it's the default).

 
 if the user clicks on the wrong button, it will navigate the user to Question #2, and for Question #2, the score will be minus2, less than 2.

```
int defaultScore = 51;



// start Play Intent
public void onPlay(View view){
    Random r = new Random();
    int XML_random = r.nextInt(5)+1; // 5 different Quiz XML files
    Intent startQuiz = new Intent();
    switch(XML_random){
    case 1:
        startQuiz.setClass(view.getContext(), Quiz_1.class);
    break;
    case 2:
        startQuiz.setClass(view.getContext(), Quiz_2.class);
    break;
    case 3:
        startQuiz.setClass(view.getContext(), Quiz_3.class);
    break;
    case 4:
        startQuiz.setClass(view.getContext(), Quiz_4.class);
    break;
    case 5:
        startQuiz.setClass(view.getContext(), Quiz_5.class);
    break;
    } // end of the Random switch
    startQuiz.putExtra("passScore", defaultScore); 
    startActivity(startQuiz); 

}
```

So, next if a random activity is chosen, then it's score will be 5, because for the first question, I want the users to start with 5 as a start. So, here is an activty(Question #1) and if the user clicks on the wrong button then Question #2 will show up. And for this activity, the score will be minus 2. Because the user chose the wrong answer.

Question 1 - user clicks on the wrong button:

```
public class Quiz_1 extends Activity {
TextView textviewScore;
int current_score = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quiz_1);
    textviewScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q_result);   // declaring the TextView 
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if (extras != null) 
     {
       current_score   = extras.getInt("passScore");
    }

    textviewScore.setText(String.valueOf(current_score));

} // end of onCreate

public void on_quiz_1_wrong(View view){  // button clicked the wrong answer
    current_score = current_score - 2;
    Intent quiz1 = new Intent(this, Quiz_2.class);
    startActivity(quiz1);
    quiz1.putExtra("passNewScore", current_score);

}
```

And here is Question #2, and for this activity i want the score to be minus 2.

```
public class Quiz_2 extends Activity {
TextView textviewScore;
int current_score = 0;
int getScore=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quiz_2);
    textviewScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q_result);   // declaring the TextView 
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if (extras != null) 
     {
       current_score   = extras.getInt("passScore");
       getScore = extras.getInt("passNewScore");
    }
    current_score = current_score - getScore;
    textviewScore.setText(String.valueOf(current_score));

} // end of onCreate
```

Comment: use shared preferences for this purpose. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref  Note : This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed). so next time your activity starts and you retrieve the score you get the values that is persisted. or use a database

Comment: Please post logcat with the exception.

Comment: in your code if random number is 6 or 0 then?

Comment: and also if you have 5 differnt xmls you let the user choose the options with a check box or radio button parse the xml depending on what user chooses and use a single activity to display the questions and you can count your score in that activity whenuse finishes answering all question navigate to scores activity and displa scores there. if you have 100 different xmls then will oyu have 100 different activity?

Comment: but, how can i display multiple xmls in one activity?

Comment: @user2547460 where is your question stored i though you have different xmls where your questions are stored. is that what you have?(not talking about layout xml here). if i have 10 questions i need not have 10 different layout xml files. i can replace the views with new data

Comment: sorry, i can;t really understand you, i store my  questions as XML files, and I THOUGHT that if i want to display an XML then i need to have an activity for that, so 10 xmls mean 10 activities, right?

Comment: @user2547460 no need for that. if you have questions stored in xml you can parse the tags in xml and display the data in the activity when user finishes choosing the option for 1 question replace the contents of with the data of new question. no need for 10 activities.

Answer (score 1):

you must first put extra to your intent then start it.

```
 quiz1.putExtra("passNewScore", current_score);
 startActivity(quiz1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the value for key "passScore" in quiz1 and calling quiz2, so how can you expect to retrieve the value on "passScore" in quiz2 ?

Pass the value for key "passScore" in quiz1.java in this method `on_quiz_1_wrong(View view)`